# Solaris shd_config file resets after restart of ssh - how to prevent this?

Tags: sftp, sshd, solaris

How do i avoid this happening, i need the sshd_config file to contain

```
Subsystem    sftp  /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server



oot@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# echo "Subsystem    sftp  /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

root@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# ls -ltr /etc/ssh/sshd_config

-rw-r--r--  1 root   sys     2435 Mar 27 12:11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

But when i restart the contents reset. Ive even tried changing permissions so that the kernel cant get at it

```
root@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# chmod 444 /etc/ssh/sshd_config

root@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# ls -ltr /etc/ssh/sshd_config

-r--r--r--  1 root   sys     2435 Mar 27 12:11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config

root@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# svcadm restart ssh                  root@uln-pca-oracle-solaris-11-2023-10-16fqbbqv:/export/home/opc# ls -ltr /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

But she still manages to get reset including permissions

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root   sys     2386 Mar 27 12:11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Post your entire `sshd_config` for us to review by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the prompt in your sample references PCA, you're probably using the Solaris OCI image bundled with it.  That is configured to use SMF stenciling to generate the sshd_config file, which would be noted in comments at the top of the file.  You can either follow the instructions in the comment to disable stenciling, or set the appropriate property on the ssh service to incorporate your configuration into the generated file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).